# Is there a legal way to get a US App Store account from outside the US?

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, accounts

I noticed that many useful applications are unavailable in Russian App Store, as US Store seems to be the primary target for developers. I wonder if there is any legal way to obtain a US Store account (I'm interested in iPhone and Mac Apps, no music) if I don't live in the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if using a fake address would be legal.

Technically, you can create an account in the US Store using an iTunes Gift Card and a fake address/phone number. You can buy iTunes Gift Cards in eBay (some sellers will expedite things by sending activation codes by email).

If you're only interested in free Apps, you can create an account without the Gift card. There is an [Apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534) describing the process.

Regardless of payment, Apple asks for a valid US address to establish an account, so the legality of this depends on where you live.

Comment: Be careful because the iTunes gift card has to be purchased in the US iTunes store for you to be able to use in the US Store

Answer (score 0):

I have a US mailing address, and  US Bank information. With this, I can purchase through the app store when I'm overseas (which is quite often). These are linked to my Apple ID.

Hope this helps.